# Irreducible polynomial over normal extension.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Let $L/K$ be a normal extension and a irreducible polynomial $f(X) \in  K[X]$. Prove that, if $f$ is reducible over $L$ then $f$ is factored into product of irreducible factors with same degree.

[This has been answer before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572796/on-irreducible-polynomial-over-normal-extension)

The proof is something like this:

Take $\bar{K}$ to be the algebraic closure of $K$. And consider $\sigma\in \textrm{Gal}(\bar{K},K)$ where $\sigma$ permutes the roots of $f$.

Now, suppose $f$ factors as the product of $f_1\cdots f_n$ over $L$. 
Since $L/K$ is normal, $σ$ is an automorphism of $L$. Let's denote $\sigma(f_i)=f_\sigma$ and suppose $\sigma \neq f_j$ ,$f_\sigma \neq f_j \forall j$. Note that the roots of $f_\sigma$ are also roots of $f$. But this means that $f_\sigma$ divides $f$ over $L$. Moreover, $f_\sigma$ and $f$ have the same degree.

After that, We can choose appropriate $\sigma$ to show that you can actually send $f_1$ to $f_j$ for any $j$.

> So what i dont understand is why  $f_\sigma$ and $f$ have the same degree.
>   And how can we choose $\sigma$ to send $f_1$ to $f_j$ for any $j$.

Comment: What is the definition of normal you are using? One can define a normal extension to be one in which any irreducible polynomial with a root in $L$ splits completely in $L$, and hence you have the irreducible factors of the same degree.

Comment: Why is that, i have various equivalences, from wikipedia Every embedding σ of L in Ka that restricts to the identity on K, satisfies σ(L) = L (σ is an automorphism of L over K.)

Comment: But I also have what you mention, but i can see why is evident for you in this case.

Comment: Well if every irreducible polynomial which has a root in $L$ splits, then you know that $L$ contains all the roots of $f$. Any automorphism of $L$ must send a root of $f$ to another root of $f$ and so you have that the automorphisms permute your irreducible factors.

Comment: Now i see, and also i understand the proof i was asking about, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)